# Implement alarm clock in Windows Phone 7.5 Mango

Tags: c#, .net, alarm, windows-phone-7

I would like create alarm clock at windows phone 7 mango , for this propose I want to use PeriodicTask is there any way to shorten the Scheduled interval from 30 minutes to every minute? Or there is better way to implement alarm clock.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periodic tasks run every 30 minutes; you cannot control when they run.

You should use the [`ScheduledActionService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) with the [`Alarm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) or [`Reminder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: I would like the Alarm to load my application when the time comes

Comment: @Sergey Then you need a Reminder : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder_members(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Reminder shows me Ok/Cancel notification :( if the user presses cancel the alarm clock is useless :(

Comment: @Sergey The user should decide not you, or?

Comment: Me Else the Alarm clock is useless

Answer (score 2):

The periodic task will fire every 30 minutes plus or minus 10 minutes.

There is no way to alter this.

This is done to maximise battery life.

If you're creating an alarm then create an [Alarm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh239249%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the alarm class as detailed here:

[WP7 Alarm Application](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-16-how.html)